# Is there a way to change the colour palette for light and dark themes in Ant Design version 5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, themes, antd

I created a hook which works well when I toggle between light and dark modes in Chrome's Rendering, panel. However, the values in the ConfigProvider do not change when the theme is toggled. Can someone explain how to hack the design token to achieve the desired result?

```js
"use client";

import '@/styles/global.scss';
import { Layout } from 'antd';
import { theme, ConfigProvider } from 'antd';
import palette from "@/styles/palette.module.scss";
import { lato, inter, futura } from '@/assets/fonts';
import { usePrefersColorScheme } from '@/hooks/index';
import { Navbar, Footer, Ribbon } from "@/components/index";

const themeConfig = {
    token: {
        components: {
            Button: {
                fontFamily: futura.style.fontFamily,
            },
            Input: {
                fontFamily: lato.style.fontFamily
            }
        },

        // typography
        fontFamily: `-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Noto Sans', sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji'`,
    }
};

// palette
const colours = {
    lucid: {
        colorInfo: palette['cyan'],
        colorError: palette['red'],
        colorPrimary: palette['blue'],
        colorWarning: palette['orange'],
        colorSuccess: palette['green'],

        colorBgLayout: palette['light']
    },
    muted: {
        colorInfo: palette['muted-cyan'],
        colorError: palette['muted-red'],
        colorPrimary: palette['muted-blue'],
        colorWarning: palette['muted-orange'],
        colorSuccess: palette['muted-green'],

        colorBgLayout: palette['dark']
    }
}

const RootLayout = ({ children }) => {
    const { token } = theme.useToken();
    const lightThemed = usePrefersColorScheme();
    const preference = (colours[lightThemed ? 'lucid' : 'muted']);

    return <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        </head>

        <ConfigProvider theme={{ ...themeConfig, ...preference }}>
            <body className={`${inter.className}`}>
                <Layout>
                    <Layout.Header style={{ background: token.colorBgLayout, lineHeight: 'normal' }}>
                        <Navbar />
                    </Layout.Header>
                    {children}
                    <Ribbon />
                    <Footer />
                </Layout>
            </body>
        </ConfigProvider>
    </html>;
};

export default RootLayout;
```

Is there anything I'm missing with using the new design token in Ant Design version 5?

Answer (score 0):

I finally cracked it. I'm using NextJS v13. And configuring React's contexts in the `layout.jsx` file in the new `app` is not supported. Solution:

1. Create a file in the `app` directory and name it `providers.jsx` ensure to mark it as a client component with `use client;` at the top of the file.
2. Nest all your client-side providers i.e theme, auth, etc
3. Use the provider in the layout of your choice.

You can find more in the Next 13 docs [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#using-context-in-client-components)

Comment: Have you used figma design token json to SCSSor is it oeiginally SCSS